# Space SQL String VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

How can i space this string so it formats with a space in between the names?

Like so 
James Marshall

At the moment it reads JamesMarshall

```
Public Function PopulateContactCmb(CompanyValue As Integer)
With Forms!MainForm!cmbContactList
.RowSource = "SELECT Contacts.ID, FirstName  " + " & LastName AS FullName FROM Contacts WHERE CompanyID = " & CompanyValue & ";"
.ColumnCount = 4
.BoundColumn = 1
.ColumnWidths = "0in.;2in.;2in.;"
```

End With

Comment: Plus (+) is usually not a good concatentator. `null + "text" = null`, whereas `null & "text" = "text"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `RowSource` assignment to something like this:

```
.RowSource = "SELECT Contacts.ID, FirstName & ' ' & LastName AS FullName FROM Contacts WHERE CompanyID = " & CompanyValue & ";"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the relevant part of the select statement to this:

```
SELECT Contacts.ID, FirstName & ' ' & LastName AS FullName
```

Edit: changed from + to & for concatenation to reflect information in a comment that I didn't think of.